# IE10 only given me an 'Unable to evaluate expression' error when changing style

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have the following javascript function to hide an HTML tag:

```
function object_Hide_obj(objectId) {

    var objname=document.getElementById(objectId);
    if (objname) {
        objname.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I have an instance where `objname` is a valid HTML `<tr>` tag. In IE10 only (works fine on IE9, IE11, Chrome, and Safari) I get a weird error on `objname.style.display = "none";`. When I Try to evaluate this in the console I get a 'Unable to evaluate expression' error, and the the browser just crashes when it reaches that line. If I debug, sometimes this doesn't happen. Does anyone know why?

Comment: try $("element").hide();

Comment: Are you using a strict DTD?

Comment: @HaBo, unfortunately not using JQuery.

Comment: @briansol, nope, transitional.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in IE10 try to install this update [KB2884101](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2884101) first

```
function object_Hide_obj(objectId) {
var objname=document.getElementById(objectId);
if (objname) {
    objname.style.display = "none";
}
```

}

> Blockquote

Place a html5 tag  start of your page and try it

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <table>
        <tr id="id0">
            <td>
                line 0
                <input type="button" onclick="object_Hide_obj('id1')" value="Hide line 1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="id1">
            <td>
                line 1
            </td>
        </tr>
```

> best of luck