# In IE10 crashes, 'Unable to evaluate expression' error occurs while accessing dom elements

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

In **IE10**, when accessing the elements by `document.getElementById('element')` it throws:

> Unable to evaluate expression

And IE10 browser crashes.

While accessing any node element's attribute like element.offsetHeight it throws the above mentioned Js error and the browser crashes (IE10)

Comment: should you  be using ie10?  It's not supported anymore

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769763/ie10-only-given-me-an-unable-to-evaluate-expression-error-when-changing-style

Comment: what is the actual code?

Comment: @Pete IE10 will continue to receive updates until Jan 2020.  Just a few more months until its end of life has been reached.

Comment: @Amy I doubt the browser share for windows server 2012 and windows embedded 8 are high enough to warrant spending extra time on still supporting the browser  all other windows operating systems have already stopped support for ie10

Comment: @Pete I wasn't arguing that the OP should continue to support IE10.  I'm only pointing out its EoL won't be reached for another 2 months.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with only the above line of code. My [test demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/yxsndk62/1/) can work well in IE 10. You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302914/unable-to-evaluate-expression) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769763/ie10-only-given-me-an-unable-to-evaluate-expression-error-when-changing-style) to see if you're in the same situation. If the issue still persists, you could provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can test it.